# Using fields from object in for-loop | twitteR

Tags: r, twitter

I am kind of a newbie to R.  I am trying to build a function to retrieve and output all the dimensions.  I am using the twitteR package which has an object 'user'.  I use the `getUser()` which outputs a 'user' class type of object.  As a part of the **twitteR** packages documentation, this object is not subsettable but does have fields such as names, screenNames, description, etc., e.g.:

```
> g <- getUser("CNN")
> g$name
[1] "CNN"
> g$screenName
[1] "CNN"
> g$description
[1] "Bringing you breaking news and the most talked about stories. Join the conversation and letâ€™s connect!"
> g$statusesCount
[1] 35605
> g$followersCount
[1] 10542191
```

This is my function that I am trying to create and am struggling with:

```
userInfo <- function(user) {
    userDims<- c("name", "screenName", "id", "lastStatus", "description", "statusesCount",                  "followersCount", "favoritesCount", "friendsCount")
    for(i in seq_along(userDims)){
        userObj <- getUser(user)
        userObj$userDims[i]
    }
}
```

**My question is:** How do I concatenate `userObj$` with each entry in `userDim` without getting this error:

```
Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
  ‘userDims’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “user”**
```

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate"? And what do you mean that the `g` object is not subsettable? I don't understand what you're trying...